# mysql query path/radius

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `city` and `city_neighbor`.

`city` contains a list of all cities while `city_neighbor` contains the neighbor(s) of a given city: `insert into city_neighbor (city_id, neighbor_id) Values(1,2)` - where neighbor_id is the id of another city from the `city` table. Nothing too fancy.

What I must build is a page where the user can select all cities in a given radius. Ex: select all cities neighboring Chicago in a radius of 5 cities for example. IMPORTANT: it's radius of 5 cities. I can't use radius of miles/km, I need to use this path style of radius (no lat/long related responses please).

Second scenario: The user wants to select all cities ordered ascending by the number of jumps (where a jump is one city which must be passed in order to get from A(Chicago) to B).

Any ideas?

P.S. My database contains ~8,000 cities.

Comment: You don't want to do this is SQL. Do it after you extract the data. Probably you will just be recursively retrieving all the neighbors of a selected city, to a depth of 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FUNCTION: CountNeighbors
IMPORT: city, depth
EXPORT: neighbors
ALGORITHM:
   neighbors = SET
   ++depth
   direct_neighbors = SELECT NEIGHBORS OF city
   neighbors += direct_neighbors
   IF depth < 5
       FOR EACH neighbor IN direct_neighbors
           neighbors += CountNeighbors(neighbor, depth, result)
```